# How to show set directory Localhost in SQL Server URL

Tags: sql-server

if you look the picture, i want to set the Server name like this : "localhost\servername",

i think just rename it , but not work .. lol

can everyone help me ?

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing this:

```
goto--> server name--><browse for more>-->Database engine-->choose--><ATI-ALR-M>
```

Comment: yoss,, okay i'm sory :D